# Rails 4 Sanitize remove style attribute from element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sanitize

I use [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) in order to clean input.
Now I need to allow adding style to span. Actually i want to allow only **specific** styles (`font-style`, `font-weight` and `text-decoration`), but at the moment I even cannot manage to allow style attribute.

I use the following configuration:

```
class Sanitize
  module Config
    ANSWER = freeze_config(
      :elements => RESTRICTED[:elements] + %w[
        iframe img a br code li ol ul p pre small strike sub sup span style
      ],

      :attributes => {
        'a'      => %w[href],
        'img'    => %w[src],
        'iframe' => %w[allowfullscreen frameborder height src width],
        'span'   => %w[style],
        'style'  => %w[font-style font-weight text-decoration],      
      },

      :add_attributes => {
        'a'       => {'rel' => 'nofollow', 'target' => '_blank'},
        'iframe'  => {'frameborder' => '0'},
      },

      :protocols => {
        'a'      => {'href' => ['http', 'https', 'mailto', :relative]},
        'img'    => {'src'  => ['http', 'https']},
        'iframe' => {'src'  => ['http', 'https', :relative]}
      },

      :at_rules_with_styles => %w[
        font-style font-weight text-decoration
      ],
    )
  end
end
```

But when I try this:

```
sanitize_settings = Sanitize::Config::ANSWER
Sanitize.fragment('<span style="color:red">rr</span>', sanitize_settings)
```

I get:

```
 => "<span>rr</span>"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is new rules for sanitizing styles and css. Easiest way to fix:

```
Sanitize::Config::ANSWER[:css]= Sanitize::Config::RELAXED[:css]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work based on latest version .

```
Sanitize.fragment('<span style="color:red">rr</span>',
   :elements => %w[div span],
   :atributes => {:all => ['style'],
   :css => {properties: Sanitize::Config::RELAXED[:css][:properties]}
  )
```

Sanitize::Config::RELAXED[:css][:properties] contains all the style properties. If you want only color properties to be allowed then specify:

```
:css => {properties: ['color']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `sanitize gem` but I think the problem is that inside `attributes` you don't have correct values for the `style`.

Try this:

```
'style'  => %w[font-style font-weight text-decoration color]
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix the sanitize filter, what I did was to use instead html tags (`<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`).

For those who have this problem using [summernote](http://summernote.org/) html editor, the solution is to set the editor like this:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
       :
       :
  styleWithSpan: false
});
```